# Removing old kernels leads to being asked for pass phrase on boot

Tags: kernel, passphrase, cryptswap

I am trying to help a friend who receives an unexpected error during startup. He used synaptic to cleanup unused kernels, and he is certain that he did not try to remove the current kernel which is `4.4.0-194-lowlatency #226-Ubuntu` according to `uname`. He is also certain that this is the only thing he did.

During startup we see

```
[  27.522396] device-mapper: table: 225:0: crypt unknown target type

Please enter passphrase for disk WDC_WDxxxxxxx-xxxx (cryptswap1) on none|:
```

When entering the passphrase,  the system starts up normally. Is this intended? If not, how do we fix it? Previously, it was not necessary to enter the passphrase during startup.

Comment: That's not an error. That looks like encrypted swap. I have never seen it happen by accident or mistake.

Comment: [This](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/) is my go-to tutorial for cleaning up old kernels. The only adjustment I needed to make was excluding `hwe` kernels by adding another `grep` command in the pipeline:
```dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | grep -E "(image|headers|modules|tools)" | grep -v "hwe" | xargs sudo apt -y purge```

Comment: How do I test the hypothesis that the swap is encrypted? I am doing debugging phone-remotely, so a brief command would be safer.